# Displaying an image in ReactJS from an API

Tags: reactjs, image, axios, blob

I am getting an image from my API using the `Axios` library. I can see the image in Postman and in the Network tab on the browser, so I know the API is sending it and Axios gets it.
But I dont know how to display it inside an `<img>`element.

This is what I've tried

```
const getPhoto = async ({jwtToken}) => {
    const apiEndpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/resources/photos/default.png'
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization' : `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
            'responseType'  : 'arraybuffer'
        }
    }
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiEndpoint, config)
        const base64 = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
        return `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`
    } catch (error) { error => {console.log(error)} }
}
```

The returned value I then store inside a variable `image`
`setImage((await getPhoto({jwtToken}) )`

and this is the `<img>` element `<img src={image} />`

But it doesnt display anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting blob data data from the backend you can use the following:-

```js
try {
    const response = await axios.get(apiEndpoint, config);
    const blob = response.data; // Binary data

    // Convert the blob to base64
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            const base64 = reader.result;
            resolve(base64);
        };

        reader.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error);
        };
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Config object const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        },
        responseType: 'blob', // Set responseType to 'blob' for binary data
    };